# Remove "Hinh" in caption on Beamer

Tags: beamer, captions

I keep getting this unwanted "Hihn" before the caption starts on Beamer.

[image]

How can I remove it? Here is my code for the figure:

```
\begin{frame}

\frametitle{\textcolor{red}{Example Slide}}

\begin{figure}[!ht]

   \begin{center}

   \includegraphics[width=6 cm, height = 6 cm]{Plot.pdf}

   \caption {\textbf{\emph{Simulation 1}}: True activity status of the corresponding cell.}

    \end{center}

\end{figure}

\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume `Hihn` is the equivalent of your language to `Figure:`. To remove this from the caption, you could redefine the `caption` template or simply not use a caption.

(replace `\usepackage[french]{babel}` in the example below with whatever language you are using)

Some other comments:

- instead of using formatting instructions in arguments of macros such as the `\frametitle` better change the appropriate beamer colour, e.g. `\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red}`
- beamer does not have a floating mechanism, giving floating specifier such as `[ht!]` does not make sense
- you don't need to center images inside beamer figures, they are centred by default
- don't specify both the height and width of an image, this will distort the image. If you must specify both, at least add `keepaspecratio`

**Solution 1**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[french]{babel}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}{%
  \raggedright
  \insertcaption\par
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Example Slide}

\begin{figure}
   \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}
   \caption{\textbf{\emph{Simulation 1}}: True activity status of the corresponding cell.}
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Solution 2**

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=red}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\frametitle{Example Slide}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=6cm]{example-image}

  \textbf{\emph{Simulation 1}}: True activity status of the corresponding cell.
\end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```